# Get average in SQL ignoring all values less than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you get the average of a column while ignoring anything less than zero, without using @TempTables? I tried this, thinking it would only set the less-than-zero values to 0, but instead it sets everything to 0 if even one value is <0.

```
[AverageCost]=avg(case when [Cost]>0 then [Cost] else 0 end)
```

Edit: To clarify, I already tried excluding them in a WHERE clause, but some columns have positive and negative values. This made the query exclude columns with an overall negative average, when it should only reject negative values when doing the average. So if a column has values of -20, -5, 5, 10, 15, then the average would be 10.

Comment: Can you post your full query?  It makes a difference.

Comment: Exclude negative values in the `where` clause; if you replace them with zero, as you're doing in your snippet, that will contribute all those zeroes to the average.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
[AverageCost] = AVG(cost)
FROM tablename
WHERE
cost > 0
```

Comment: Looking back at my query, I also added `AVG(CAST(cost as float))`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you can limit your entire query (Which isn't entirely clear yet), you could do this:

```
DECLARE @AverageCost int;
SELECT @AverageCost = AVG(Cost)
FROM TableName
WHERE Cost > 0
```

Your answer is probably going to look somethign like that regardless - for example, set the variable first and then run your whole query:

```
UPDATE SomeOtherTable
SET AverageCost = @AverageCost, AnotherField = FieldB
FROM TableName
-- now we don't have to exclude negative values.
```

Alternatively, you could keep something close to what you had:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Cost > 0 THEN Cost ELSE NULL END)
FROM TableName
```

This will have a similar effect without limiting your entire query - but note the difference, NULL instead of 0 (think about the difference between averaging in a 0 vs skipping a value).